# How do i display validation error from controller using angularjs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and totally confused,i am trying below code and dont know if it is right way.

`index.html`

```
<div class="input-group" ng-controller="validationController">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
    <%= text_field_tag :checkindate, params[:checkindate], :placeholder => 'Select Date',  :class=>'form-control datepicker input-lg',:required=>true,"ng-model" => "checkin.date"%>

</div>


<div class="input-group" ng-controller='validationController'>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
    <%= text_field_tag :checkoutdate, params[:checkoutdate],:placeholder => 'Select Date', :class=>'form-control datepicker input-lg',:required=>true,"ng-model" => "checkout.date"%>
</div>

<p ng-show='isInvalidDate()'>Checkout Date Cannot be lesser than Checkin Date</p>
```

`validationController.js`

```
App.controller('validationController',['$scope', function($scope){
$scope.isInvalidDate = function(){
    return $scope.checkout.date < $scope.checkin.date;
}
}]) ;
```

`App.js`

```
var App = angular.module('App',[]);
```

Now when I select check out date lesser than checkin date, error is not displayed. Can someone please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `controller` only works on the DOM-element it is declared on and its children.

```
<p ng-show='isInvalidDate()'>Checkout Date Cannot be lesser than Checkin Date</p>
```

Is outside the scope of both your controllers.

Since you're trying to compare the value of both `input`s, you'd need to have both of them and the `p` holding your error message inside a single DOM element with the `ng-controller` attribute.

Also, the way you are using the `ng-controller` attributes seems to suggest you think of it as  a singleton. It is not. In your case you have two instances of the `controller`, one of them knows about the checkin-date and the other one knows about the checkout-date. Neither of them would be able to actually perform the validaiton.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how do i modify the above code?, since i have to use separate <div> tags for input groups.

Comment: Well, you could probably remove the `ng-controller='validationController'` from both input groups and then wrap everything in a `<div>` and put `ng-controller` on that.